# How to toggle an element that uses scroll (function)?

Tags: jquery

I have an element that is set to disappear when the user scrolls down in the browser window. I also want that element to toggle its visibility when another element is clicked.

Here's what I have, but the toggle visible/invisible does not work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $(".product-down-scroll").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
    });

    $('.pricing-tab').click(function() {
        $('.product-down-scroll').toggle();
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="pricing-accordion">
    <div class="pricing-tab">
        <input id="tab" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
        <label for="tab">PRICING</label>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor si amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to accomplish that?

Comment: Without the [mcve] we won't be able to debug this issue.

Comment: I have added some new information

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
$('.pricing-tab').click(function(){
  $('.product-down-scroll').toggle();
});
```

Binds the `click` event to the element `<div class="pricing-tab"></div>`. Since that `<div>` does not have any content, it has a `height` of `0` and is unable to be clicked on.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craftman32/xpvt214o/783805/) with a suggestion to use a `<button>` element to toggle the `<div class="pricing-tab"></div>` element.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. The pricing-tab div isn't actually empty. There is content in there that's visible when the accordion is collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

`toggle()` is not changing the opacity of your element, it un/sets `display: none`.
Instead of using `toggle()` you should set the opacity back to 1.

```
$('.pricing-tab').click(function(){
  $('.product-down-scroll').css('opacity',1);
});
```

Comment: Tried this. The .product-down-scroll was unaffected by the click function. So essentially nothing happens...

Comment: @mmhnyc1220 sorry then, but maybe I just don't understand, what you'd like to achieve. here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/790212/

Comment: I think the issue is that the code worked when clicking on the rest of the div but not on the text "Pricing" itself. I think it's because of the 'label for="tab"' inside the div

Comment: No big deal though, you can simply bind your click handler to the label instead of `.pricing-tab` itself.

Comment: If I wanted to be more specific and bind the handler specifically only to the .pricing-tab selector, is that possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean because it's explicitly bound to `.pricing-tab`. Considering your own answer... maybe you want to use `$('.pricing-tab label')` instead? This will bind click to all label within the pricing-tab

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
$("label[for='tab']").click(function(){
$('.product-down-scroll').toggle();
});
```

But how do I get more specific by specifying that only the label in the .pricing-tab selector should be affected?